# Association rules algorithmn

Tags: r, data-mining

I have this transactions in csv file.

---

```
I1,I2,I5  
I2,I4  
I2,I3  
I1,I2,I4  
I1,I3  
I2,I3  
I1,I3  
I1,I2,I3,I5  
I1,I2,I3
```

---

With `support=0.02` and `confidence=0.8` the association rules are `{I1, I2, I3}` and `{I1, I2, I5}`. This is from Data Mining, Concepts and Techniques book.
I wrote the code in R and with this support I only get one rule, `{I1,I2,I5}`

---

The code in R:

```
transactions <- read.transactions("file.csv", sep=",")
m1<-apriori(transactions, parameter = list(support=0.02, minlen=3))
inspect(sort(m1, by="support"))
```

[image]

Comment: please share your code, also mention if you are using the `arules` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{I1, I2, I3} is **not an association rule**.

It is a **frequent item set**.

The left hand side of an association rule must be a frequent itemset, but not every frequent itemset will occur in the left hand side of a rule.

So you cannot rely on looking at the lhs of association rules to find all frequent itemsets.

In your Apriori association rules, the last two rules were generated from the itemset  {I1, I2, I3, I5} (the *union* of lhd and rhs must be a frequent itemset, too). But again,don't rely on association rules if you want to find frequent itemsets. They are not exactly the same.